# How to change the time to summer time

Tags: php, time

I am living in Quebec, which is in EST time zone.

When I use

```
date_default_timezone_set('EST');
echo date("m/d/Y h:i:s");
```

I will get the time that's one hour different than my current time.

Now I can only manually correct the time using

```
$time = strtotime('+1 hour');
echo date("m/d/Y h:i:s",$time);
```

I don't know how to make the program to change the time to summer time automatically.

I heard that `date("I")` would return true if it is in the summer time?

I am not sure about that.

Comment: EST is Eastern Standard Time. For 'summer time' you probably want EDT.

Comment: Have you tried `America/New_York` or `America/Toronto` (both eastern I believe) and are included in the List of Supported Timezones as per - http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Find the right timezone for your region.  Trying to hack this manually is not advisable because you are likely to get it wrong using `strtotime()` depending on the hour of the day.

Comment: @DaveCoast The New York time zone works. The reason why I use EST is that I can’t find my province or my city (Montreal) on the PHP website. I don’t know which time zone to use.... Thanks for telling me that I am in the same time zone of New York!

Comment: @Kevin Thanks ! I would not know that we are in EDT if you did not tell me that!

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks, I will try my best for using another method instead of strtotime(). It was the first time me using it and I feel this method magical!

Answer (score 2):

`EST` would be Eastern Standard Time. You're looking for Eastern Daylight Savings Time. Best to choose your locale from [the supported locations](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php) so that you don't have to manually keep track of this.

For example, here's New York which is DST right now (2017-08-11):

https://3v4l.org/pdeQu

```
<?php

echo date_default_timezone_get() . ' : ' . date("m/d/Y h:i:s") . PHP_EOL;

date_default_timezone_set('EST');

echo date_default_timezone_get() . ' : ' . date("m/d/Y h:i:s") . PHP_EOL;

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

echo date_default_timezone_get() . ' : ' . date("m/d/Y h:i:s") . PHP_EOL;
```

> ```
> UTC : 08/11/2017 03:54:07
> EST : 08/10/2017 10:54:07
> America/New_York : 08/10/2017 11:54:07
> ```

Comment: You solved my problem 100%! Thanks for writing the code so I can take it as a reference !